# Delete node from AST in Go

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there any way to delete specific type node from AST? (for example, i want to delete all Expr Statements) Or maybe there is a way to replace it with empty ast.Expr node?

I didnt find any documentation about it so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

UPD:

```
func find_node(file *ast.File) {

    ast.Inspect(file, func(node ast.Node) bool {

        switch x := node.(type) {

        case *ast.ExprStmt:

           var e ast.Expr
           e = x.X

           fmt.Printf("Expression found: %s\n", e)

        }

    return true
})
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code you have now?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I'm just using ast.Inspect to find Expr statements but I have no idea what should I do to remove them

Comment: `ast.Node` has `Pos()` and `End()` methods which return an abstract position (convert it into something more helpful with `fset.Position`). Would it be acceptable to use those to determine a range of characters to remove from the file, remove them, write the file to disk and then re-read it?

Comment: Have you tried `ast.FilterFile()`?

Comment: See the ast.Filter* functions as mentioned by @kichik. If the existing functions don't meet your needs, then use them as starting point for your own filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [astutil](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil#Cursor.Delete) package. See the delete example in the tests at [rewrite_test.go](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/go/ast/astutil/rewrite_test.go#L123).